# Mudar formulario quando digitado

Tags: html

Tenho uma pagina, onde eu pesquiso por nome, cpf ou contrato e estou com dificuldade em trocar o tamanho do formulário quando for digitando.

Penso assim, quando começar a digitar os caracteres, já sabe que é pelo nome e aparece o form do tamanho x, se eu começar a digitar número, verifica se for maior que 6 números é cpf e já insere a mascara ao digitar e se começar a digitar números e for menor que 11 é contrato.

Eu utilizo este dado para pesquisar numa *query* em SQL Server 2012, conforme o valor digitado no `input`.

```
<span style="color: #ffffff"><strong>Contrato:</strong></span>
<input name="inpcont" type="text" required  id="inpcont" placeholder="Buscar..." onBlur="MM_validateForm('inpcont','','RisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="08" maxlength="8"/>
<input id="btnBusca" type="image" src="img/lupasemfundo-22x22.png" vspace="0" hspace="0" onclick="index.php.frmbuscacontrato.submit()"/>
```

Comment: Poste o código e o que você já tentou fazer aqui. Só na explicação fica difícil entender.

Comment: Bom dia Willian, aqui está o codigo que utilizo:  
<form name="frmbuscacontrato" method="post" action="index.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <span style="color: #ffffff"><strong>Contrato:</strong></span>
  <input name="inpcont" type="text" required  id="inpcont" placeholder="Buscar..." onBlur="MM_validateForm('inpcont','','RisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" size="08" maxlength="8"/><input id="btnBusca" type="image" src="img/lupasemfundo-22x22.png" vspace="0" hspace="0" onclick="index.php.frmbuscacontrato.submit()"/>

Comment: mas preciso mudar para algo do tipo: se no inpcont for caracter ao ir digitando, muda o tamanho do formulario, se ao digitar no inpcont começar digitar número, faz verificação de tamanho e se for maior que 6, é cpf e se for até 10 é contrato e ajuste o form

Comment: Faça igual eu fiz, edite a pergunta com o javascript. Não colocando no comentário.

Comment: Quando for colocar o código fonte, selecione ele e aperte o botão `{ }` assim ele sai formatado.

Comment: Sua dúvida é apenas com a estilização do `input`? As tags `php` e `sql-server` são dispensáveis.

Comment: Sou  novato aqui, mas em todas as pesquisas que já fiz sobre programação, foi aqui que eu encontrei as melhores respostas. Por este motivo sou grato a todos desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o plugin `mask` do jquery, aplicar a máscara somente quando o valor do input for numérico e removê-la caso tenha a entrada de algum outro caractere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#nomeCpf").on('keyup', function(e) {

    if ($(this).data('mask') == undefined && $.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
      $(this).mask('000.000.000-00', {
        reverse: false
      });
    } else if($(this).mask) {
      $(this).unmask();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<span><strong>Contrato:</strong></span>
<input id="nomeCpf" name="inpcont" type="text" required id="inpcont" placeholder="Buscar..." size="12" />
```